The slot resource was not found error, cannot launch web app. I did dot create such slot I am in B1 plan
My current context is
Have azure account, subscription to basic plan
Locally, I am using MacBook Pro sequoia 15
Backend is express.js sequelize, tedious, migration, works and can connect to a database located in azure sql database. It worked.
in order to set up my backend app as an  azure web app, I already set the following resources :
Managed identity : vcpBasicPlanExpressAppManagedIdentity
Resource group  : vcpBasicPlanExpressAppResourceGroup
Server : vcpbasicplanexpressappserver
User name : username
Password : password
Database : vcpBasicPlanExpressAppDatabase
Web App : vcpBasicPlanExpressAppWebApp

I chose the following parameters

    Source : GitHub 
    Organization : laclauderie
    Repository : vcpBasicPlanExpressApp10Oct2024
    Branch : main
    Runtime stack : Node
    Version : Node 20LTS
Authentication type : user-assigned identity
Subscription : Azure subscription 1
Identity : vcpBasicPlanExpressAppServiceManagedIdentity

When wanting to run my web app, I get the following error :
{
    "shellProps": {    
        "sessionId": "3b97a1e45e10408da2939e607130d7c5",    
        "extName": "HubsExtension",
        "contentName": "ResourceMenuBlade",
        "resourceId": "/subscriptions/4588ceb1-9d18-4e3b-98c1-fd95f2b224ad/resourceGroups/vcpbasicplanexpressappresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/vcpbasicplanexpressappwebapp/slots/g4hwaqgebvfedpdn"
    },
    "error": {    
        "message": "Resource not found",
        "code": 404,
        "details": { 
            "htmlTemplate": "The resource was not found, it may have been deleted. If this was launched from a pinned tile on the dashboard, it should be removed.<br /><br />Resource ID: /subscriptions/4588ceb1-9d18-4e3b-98c1-fd95f2b224ad/resourceGroups/vcpbasicplanexpressappresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/vcpbasicplanexpressappwebapp/slots/g4hwaqgebvfedpdn<br /><br />Status Code: 404<br /><br />Status Message: The Resource &#39;Microsoft.Web/sites/vcpbasicplanexpressappwebapp/slots/g4hwaqgebvfedpdn&#39; under resource group &#39;vcpbasicplanexpressappresourcegroup&#39; was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix"
        }
  }
}

I did dot create such slot I am in B1 plan
May be this error comes because of the database connection. Indeed with a simple express
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('App is running!');
    });

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });

It works
Can you help me ?
Indeed with a simple express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('App is running!');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

It works, i can launch my web app

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  For future reference, please refrain from including any credentials.
